# pig script fail on HUE Browser

Tags: hadoop, hue

I have the following pig script:

```
data = LOAD '/user/test/text.txt' as (text:CHARARRAY) ;

DUMP data;
```

When I run this in SHELL it work but FAIL When run in HUE Browser

This is the output log:

```
2015-08-19 15:42:21,033 [JobControl] ERROR com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader  - Could not load native gpl library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(GPLNativeCodeLoader.java:32)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec.<clinit>(LzoCodec.java:71)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2051)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2016)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat.isSplitable(TextInputFormat.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:397)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any one have met this error before please help me

Thanks

Comment: Hue submits the Pig scripts with Oozie, which will run it from a node in the cluster. Is the lzo installed properly there?

Comment: In my case, all service installed in one server datanode + namdenode + hue ..., follow you how can I check ? I use the command rpm -qa | grep lzo  and here is the result :

hadoop-lzo-0.4.15+cdh5.4.5+0-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.8.el6.x86_64

impala-lzo-2.2.0+cdh5.4.5+0-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.8.el6.x86_64

lzo-2.03-3.1.el6_5.1.x86_64

lzop-1.02-0.9.rc1.el6.x86_64

hadoop-lzo-debuginfo-0.4.15+cdh5.4.5+0-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.8.el6.x86_64

lzo-devel-2.03-3.1.el6_5.1.x86_64

hadoop-lzo-mr1-0.4.15+cdh5.4.5+0-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.8.el6.x86_64

lzo-minilzo-2.03-3.1.el6_5.1.x86_64

Comment: I had fixed the problem here it is:
sudo -u oozie hadoop fs -put /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/*  /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150730103317/pig/